# How to replace single occurrence of a character in a Java string

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string where it contains different combinations of the slashes

```
{"result":"{\"cov_details\":[{\"issue_date\":\"UNIT 
 OFFICE,NEYVELI\",\"cov\":\"MCWG\"}],\"dl_number\":\"TN31Y200000784\",\"address\":\"PERIYA COLONY  KO 
 PAVAZHANGUDI  VIRUDHACHALAM TK\",\"issue_date\":\"24-03-2010\",\"dob\":\"21-03- 
 1981\",\"name\":\"VICNESWARAN S\",\"blood_group\":\"\",\"validity\":{\"transport\":\"\",\"non- 
 transport\":\"4-01-2010 to 23-03-2040\"},\"father\\\/husband\":\"SELVAM\"}","status- 
 code":"101","request_id":"a2642ae9-2f10-4e9a-9f7e-c3ee1a9a2dbe"}
```

I want to replace all occurances of a single "" alone but ignore when "" is followed by "/" ( check out the 
 `father\\\/husband\`  parameter. It should read `father\/husband`. How can I achieve this in Java?

Comment: Question is not clear. In father\\\/husband\, there is no double quote. Please add clarity. Can you provide complete expected output sting for the input string.

Comment: This is JSON content and you should be using a parser here.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide "\/" by replacing it with another character sequence like "~~~", then restore it after:

```
    String string = "father\\\\\\/husband\\";
    
    System.out.println("Before\t:\t" + string);
    
    System.out.println
    (
        "After\t:\t" + string
                            .replaceAll("\\\\/", "~~~")
                            .replaceAll("\\\\", "")
                            .replaceAll("~~~", "\\\\/")
    );
```

**Output:**

```
Before  :   father\\\/husband\
After   :   father\/husband
```

Answer (score -1):

`public String replaceAll​(String regex, String replacement)` accepts regex as the first parameter:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Fill free to specify any pattern you need:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Comment: It would be helpful to add more details as to how the person can use the function in his use case. Not to encourage copypasta but perhaps make the answer more complete.